# What's wrong with javascript ternary operator in my app?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple discount app with prompt input. 
The problem is in my ternary operator - it doesn't count the newPrice as well as show that input is invalid. 
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I if the input is wrong I want to assign newPrice to null and alert 'Invalid data'

My code:

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

const newPrice = ((9999999 > price > 0) && (99 > discount > 0)) ? (price - price * discount / 100) : (null, alert('Invalid data'));
console.log(newPrice)
```

Comment: probably an operator precedence thing. when in doubt, put more parenthesis around things

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox Dev console

Comment: please check your conditions and if you are having lot of decision making then why can't you go with if-else conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating out the code statements to

1. make sure new price is actually null. Not `undefined`. (per your question)
2. the `a > b > c` stuff does not work afaik in JS. Please refactor that syntax as i did below or similar.

```js
const price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
const discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');

const newPrice = (price && (9999999 > price) && discount && (99 > discount)) ? (price - price * discount / 100) : null;
console.log(newPrice);
if(!newPrice){alert('Invalid data');}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt may be reading the value as a string.
Convert it to number using `parseInt` or unary `+`

```
const price = parseInt(prompt('Please, enter the price:'));
const discount = parseInt(prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:'));

const newPrice = ((price && price > 0 && price < 9999999) && (discount && discount >0 && discount < 99 )) ? (price - price * discount / 100) : (null, alert('Invalid data'));
console.log(newPrice)
```

Comment: string and number comparison works fine when the string only contains numbers

Comment: @ChrisRollins It doesn't, try `console.log('10' > '9');`.

Comment: moot. good question though. the input prompt is actually taking the number as a number (you can run the code snippet here in SO) and doing the substraction math correctly.

Comment: so it's not necessary to add `+` or `parseInt` before `prompt`?

Comment: @Teemu that would be string and string

Comment: It is wiser to do that, since any NaN values can also be checked.

Comment: @ChrisRollins Yeah, but in general your code should not rely on automatic type coercion.

Comment: The above code will automatically fail if the input is not valid number since NaN has a falsy boolean value

Comment: @Teemu in general I would agree, but it wasn't the issue in this code so this answer is wrong, which is why I made that comment. Also if you want to point out problems in the code it would be that there is no validation of the user input string. So even if you avoid using type coercion you aren't really fixing anything anyway.

Comment: @Chris, I have updated it since, but my first instinct was the incorrect comparison that could've potentially caused the error. Apparently that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your inputs to numbers, and second, refactor your conditions to be valid (you can't have `x > y > z` IIRC):

```js
const price = parseInt(prompt('Please, enter the price:'));
const discount = parseInt(prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:'));

const newPrice = (((9999999 > price) && price) && ((99 > discount) && discount)) ? (price - price * discount / 100) : (null, alert('Invalid data'));
console.log(newPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of doing by both method `if-else` and ternary operator (`?:`). But I would recommend going with `if-else` if you have much decision makings.

```js
var price = prompt('Please, enter the price:');
var discount = prompt('Please, enter the discount amount:');
var newPrice;
if((price>0 && price < 9999999)&&(discount>0 && discount < 99)){
newPrice=price - (price * discount) / 100;
}else{
newPrice='null';
alert('Invalid data');
}
var newPrice1 = ((9999999 > price && price > 0) && (99 > discount && discount > 0)) ? (price - (price * discount) / 100) : ('null', alert('Invalid data'));
console.log(newPrice);
console.log(newPrice1);
```